# Custom Firefox service not starting after reboot

Tags: firefox, services, kiosk

I am currently building a kiosk for a local sports club and I am running into a few issues here and there.

Since multiple pages have to be loaded at the beginning, I opted to use Firefox which will use ubuntu-frame.

You can find the whole configuration and installation guide here: https://gitlab.com/raQai/firefox-kiosk

During testing the `kiosk.service` started up fine and I was able to stop/restart it multiple times.
Once I enabled the service and reboot the machine, Firefox no longer opens and I am stuck at the empty `ubuntu-frame` display.

Funny part about this: I can no longer start the service at all and I cannot find any logs which explain this behaviour...

Just learned recently about `ubuntu-frame` so this might be complete bs what I am trying to do here. Please help :)

```
[Unit]
Description=Firefox Kiosk
After=snap.ubuntu-frame.daemon.service
After=getty.target
Conflicts=display-manager.service
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
Environment=WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0
Environment=MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1
Environment=HOME=/root
Environment=XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0
Environment=XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
Environment=DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/0/bus
ExecStart=firefox-esr -P default
Nice=15

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

```
systemctl status kiosk
○ kiosk.service - Firefox Kiosk
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kiosk.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)

Jan 21 15:47:34 rq-ThinkPad-X201 systemd[1]: Started Firefox Kiosk.
Jan 21 15:47:35 rq-ThinkPad-X201 firefox-esr[2641]: Missing chrome or resource URL: resource://gre/modules/UpdateListener.jsm
Jan 21 15:47:35 rq-ThinkPad-X201 firefox-esr[2641]: Missing chrome or resource URL: resource://gre/modules/UpdateListener.sys.mjs
Jan 21 15:47:35 rq-ThinkPad-X201 systemd[1]: kiosk.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

Update 1:
By disabling the process, killing all Firefox related processes and running

```
sudo \ 
  WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0 \
  MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1 \
  HOME=/root
  XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0 \
  XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop \
  DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/0/bus \
  firefox-esr -P default
```

I found out, that Firefox starts with a window saying:

> Firefox closed unexpectedly while starting. This might be caused by add-ons or other problems. You can try to resolve the problem by troubleshooting in Safe Mode.

The command exits immediately with `0` which does not match the behavior when starting without the crash dialog. Clicking the `Open` button starts Firefox as expected but the command line no longer manages this process.
Regularly closing Firefox and running the command again, I can start Firefox as expected and the process remains in the current shell, no `exit 0` until the window is closed.

I guess the service runs into issues since it constantly restarts due to the `exit 0` behavior.

This happens every time the process is killed, e.g. by using `Ctrl+C` if the process was started from the command line. I actually want to be able to kill the process since I want to kill it if no user is interacting with the kiosk. This means I require to be able to ignore this dialog and not terminate with `exit 0` unless the process was actually killed/closed.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Your status output shows `kiosk.service` as `disabled`. Try re-enabling it.

Comment: Yea, disabled it due to the autostart. re-enabling results in a loop of `Active: active (running)` followed by `Active: activating (aut-restart)` containing this info `Process: 174124 ExecStart=firefox-esr -P default (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like my finding in Update 1 was correct.

It also seems like the error/crash dialog cannot be ignored by any way I have found online (e.g. preferences or `MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_DISABLE=1`).

To "fix" this issue I introduced a [new script](https://gitlab.com/raQai/firefox-kiosk/-/blob/main/firefox_pre.sh) which will now clean the whole `.mozilla` folder and copy expected css files back into place. Paired with `ExecStartPre` this will basically wipe all data whenever the service restarts and ignore previous sessions completely.